# Insert value in the next column so that it does not match 2 previous column in a table?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, algorithm

I have a Agent table in database. The structure is as follows:

```
information(id,name,group) and 12 columns containing months values(month1,month2,....).
```

Images of tables are attached. Each month should have evaluator assigned to corresponding agent. I have 21 Evaluators and Evaluation table is like:

```
(Id(EvaluatorId), Group(to which he belongs),Quantity(how many times he can be assigned to agent))
```

So, the problem that I face is that I can not assign all of them. I think there is a problem with my sql query which selects randomly not assigned agent from Agent table.

Agent table:
[image]
Evaluation table:
[image]

This is what I wrote in my API side:

```
 List<Integer> results=new ArrayList<>();

        List<Evaluation> evaluations= evaluationRepository.findTop1000ByOrderByEvaluatorAsc();
        for (Evaluation evaluation : evaluations) {

                for (int i = 0; i < evaluation.getQuantity(); i++) {

                    Agent agent=AgentRepository.getNotAssignedAgent(evaluation.getGroup(),LocalDate.now().getMonthValue(),evaluation.getEvaluator());

                    System.out.println(agent.getId()+" : "+evaluation.getGroup()+" : "+evaluation.getEvaluator());
                    results.add((int)agent.getId());
                    AgentRepository.updateAgent((int)agent.getId(),LocalDate.now().getMonthValue(),evaluation.getEvaluator());
                }
            return results;

        }
```

Method to get not assigned agent from Agent table in AgentRepository:

```
 public Agent getNotAssignedAgent(int groupType,int monthId,int evaluator) {
        String sql="Select TOP(1) Id,Agent,GroupType From [AgentAllocator].[dbo].[Agent] Where GroupType="+groupType+" AND ["+ monthId +"] is null AND ( ["+(monthId-1)+"] <>"+evaluator+" Or "+(monthId-1)+" is null ) AND ( ["+(monthId-2)+"] <>"+evaluator+" Or "+(monthId-2)+" is null ) Order by rand()";
        Agent agent=new Agent();
        try{
            Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet=statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                agent.setAgent(resultSet.getString(2));
                agent.setGroupType(Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString(3)));
                agent.setId(Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString(1)));
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return agent;
    }
```

Sample query:

```
Select TOP(1) Id,Agent,GroupType From [AgentAllocator].[dbo].[Agent] Where GroupType=1 AND [6] is null AND ( [5] <>21 Or [5] is null ) AND ( [4] <>21 Or [4] is null ) Order by rand();
```

Method to update Agent table in AgentRepository:

```
 @Override
    public int updateAgent(int agentId,int month, int value){
        String sql="Update [AgentAllocator].[dbo].[Agent] set ["+month+"] ="+value+" WHERE Id="+agentId;
        int res=-100;
        try{
            Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
            res=statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  res;
    }
```

My expected result is: All of the evaluators in evaluation table should be assigned to agent. No one should be left. There are 311 Agents and 21 Evalutors who should be assigned 283 times.
When I run the api I get 241 Agents assigned out of 283.

Comment: If I look at your database design, alarm bells are starting to ring in my head: Do you really want 12 columns representing the 12 month in the agent table? Are you sure you are never gonna need the data of the previous or next year? I would put the assignments in another table AgentEvaluatorAssignment, one assignment on a row, e.g. ID, AgentID, EvaluatorID, StartDate (containing 01. + month + year), EndDate (containing the last day of the month + month + year). This allows you to react for unpredict situations: Emergency replacement of an agent within a month but still having the history...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Christoph . I just put it in that way so it would be more understandable and easy to read. The data would be stored for one year only.